# Create a formal linear function in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have an expression in Sympy (like

```
-M - n + x(n)
```

) and I would 
like to create a formal linear function, says f, and apply it to my expression, in order to get, after simplification:

```
-f(M) - f(n) + f(x(n))
```

Is it possible to tell sympy that a property such as linearity is verified?

A very hacky way to do it would be to apply the function f to every subexpression which is in a sum.
For instance when given an expressions like the first one I gave, it would be nice to simply access the terms appearing in the sum (here it would be

```
[-M, -n , x(n)]
```

Then mapping f on the list and sum it to get what is expected.

Is there an easy way to do so, or have I necessarily to go trough the syntactic tree of the expression ?

Comment: You could think of f as an operator and write `f*(-M - n + x(n))`.

Comment: I found out in the meanwhile that if S is an expression representing a sum , S.args returns the list of the constitutive elements. Then the strategy I gave works fine (even if it is hacky)

Comment: You can use `Add.make_args(S)` which works even if S isn't a sum.

Comment: @user70925 If you have found a solution to your problem, you can post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> x,f = map(Function, 'xf'); n,M = symbols('n,M'); expr = -M - n + x(n)
>>> Add(*[f(a) for a in Add.make_args(expr)])
f(-M) + f(-n) + f(x(n))
```

If you have an expression like `f(n*(M + 1))` and you expand it you will get `f(n*M + n)`. Can you tell SymPy to apply the function to the args of `f`'s args? Yes:

```
>>> expr = f(n*(M + 1))
>>> expr.expand().replace(lambda x: x.func == f,
...         lambda x: Add(*[f(a) for a in Add.make_args(x.args[0])]))
f(n) + f(M*n)
```

If you call such a replacement `linapp` you can use it for any function that you want:

```
def linapp(expr, *f):
    return expr.expand().replace(
      lambda x: x.func in f,
      lambda x: Add(*[x.func(a) for a in Add.make_args(x.args[0])]))

>>> print(linapp(cos(x+y) + sin(x + y), cos, sin))
sin(x) + sin(y) + cos(x) + cos(y)
```

(Not saying that it's a true result, just that you can do it. And if you replace a variable with something else and you want to reapply the linearization, you can:

```
>>> linapp(_.subs(y, z + 1), cos)
sin(x) + sin(z + 1) + cos(x) + cos(z) + cos(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hackey way that goes through the syntactic tree:

```
from sympy import *
init_session()
M,n=symbols('M n')
thing=-f(M) - f(n) + f(x(n))
def linerize_element(bro):
    return bro.args[0] if len(bro.args) == 1 else bro.args[0] * bro.args[1].args[0]
print([ linerize_element(tmp) for tmp in thing.args])
```