# Manipulating sympy expression trees

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Lets say, we have a sympy function cos(x). Every function can be 
presented by a tree, e.g. like the image here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsAsTrees.html

I want to insert a parameter into every node of this expression tree, that means

```
cos(x) -> a*cos(b*x)
```

For more complicated expression, it should look like

```
(exp(x)+cos(x)*x)/(x) -> h*(b*exp(a*x)+f*(c*cos(d*x)*e*x))/(j*x)
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j are parameters, that I want to fit.

A helpful source could be https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html in the chapter "walking the tree". I tried to replace parts of the 
`expr.args` 
tuple, but it is not possible.

This is the expression:

```
from simply import symbols, exp, cos
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = (exp(x)+cos(x)*y)/(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
>>> s = numbered_symbols('C')
>>> cform = ((exp(x)+cos(x)*x)/(x)).replace(
...    lambda x:not x.is_Number,
...    lambda x:x*next(s))
>>> cform
C1*C8*C9*(C2*C4*C5*x*cos(C3*x) + C7*exp(C6*x))/(C0*x)

>>> from sympy.solvers.ode import constantsimp, constant_renumber

>>> constantsimp(cform, [i for i in cform.atoms(Symbol) if i.name.startswith('C')])
C0*(C2*x*cos(C3*x) + C7*exp(C6*x))/x
>>> constant_renumber(_)
C1*(C2*x*cos(C3*x) + C4*exp(C5*x))/x
>>> eq = _
>>> cons = ordered(i for i in eq.atoms(Symbol) if i.name.startswith('C'))
>>> eq.xreplace(dict(zip(cons, var('a:z'))))
a*(b*x*cos(c*x) + d*exp(e*x))/x
```

Comment: The constant_renumber(_) function seems to miss the required arguments 'symbolname', 'startnumber', and 'endnumber'
While the first two can easily be put there, I would like to keep the endnumber not fixed but depending on the expression that you put inside. Is that possible?

Also vars is not defined and it says, that for eq, a "'str' object has no attribute 'atoms'"

Comment: I rechecked the code as it appears on this page. It ran without modification as shown. If your version of SymPy requires more arguments it is perhaps an older version. And note that the function is `var`, not `vars`.

Comment: See also a related question about applying a linear function to the terms of its arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924562/1089161).